# Allowing single group having access permission of multiple groups

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod, folder-permissions, chgrp

I would like to know one thing about linux (ubuntu) permission commands.

I am having couple of user groups in my linux environment

1) **www-data** -> Created by nginx automatically

2) **ubuntu** -> Just for PHP uses

Now both are having their own different writing permissions .. I would like to merge them both as single user group ..

**Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved that same sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu OR sudo chown -R www-data:ubuntu \folder\to\give\permission And by that above command I also got ubuntu permission also